# deleting facebook requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

The facebook docs [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) say "it is the Developers' responsibility to delete a Request once it has been accepted". As far as I understand, when someone sends a request to multiple users on facebook like this:

```
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
  FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
   message: 'test message'
   }, requestCallback);
}
```

only one request_id is returned via requestCallback() function. 
Then, if I delete the request when someone accepts it, how would other users accept the deleted request?

Answer (score 2):

when user comes following the app request, you can get request id's using

```
$_GET['request_ids']
```

then retrieve all the request ids with which you can call graph api to delete the corresponding requests like below:

```
if(isset($_GET['request_ids']))
{
    $request_ids = $_GET['request_ids'];
}
$request_ids = explode(",", $request_ids);
foreach($request_ids as $request_id)
{

        $full_request_id = $request_id."_".$fbid;  //$fbid is current user facebook id
        $facebook->api("$full_request_id","DELETE");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the *Request ID Format* section of [the FB request overview page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/).

The actual graph path for a request actually sent to specific user is "request-id"_"recipient-user-id".

Answer (score 0):

you can access to facebook on mobile mode (**m.faceook.com**)

1-access the invitation panel

2-display all the invitations

3-open console mode in chrome

4-activate jquery by cpying and pasting all the **jquery.min** code into console
and excecute this script :

```
$("._54k8._56bs._56bt").trigger("click");
```

that will cancel or the invitation sent